# Cannot include figures via R/Sweave/LaTeX

Tags: r, plot, latex, sweave

I am trying to create a pdf vs R/Sweave/LaTeX that will include a plot. Here is the relevant snippet from my .Rnw file:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
makeMyPlot()
@
\end{center}
\label{fig:one}
\end{figure}
```

When I run Sweave it generates a .pdf file named "analysis report-005.pdf" and a .tex file including the following line:

```
\includegraphics{analysis report-005.pdf}
```

So far, so good. But when I run

```
tools::texi2pdf('analysis report.tex')
```

I get this error

```
Error: running 'texi2dvi' on 'analysis report.tex' failed

LaTeX errors:
:218: LaTeX Error: File `analysis report-005' not found.
```

It looks like texi2pdf is failing to find the file because the extension, ".pdf", is not stated in the .tex file output. When I add ".pdf" directly to the relevant line of the .tex file, the error goes away. However, I shouldn't need to do this manually. I'm not sure if this is a problem with Sweave or texi2pdf; I suspect the latter. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try a file name without spaces maybe? You can also experiment with knitr instead of Sweave.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{grffile}` to your document preamble. See [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/5764)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the spaces were the problem. I just took out the spaces and now it works fine. Thanks!